# Unable to find elements using Cheerio (Node.js/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to write a script to scrape a users achievements from their public Codecademy profile. Currently, this is how I'm trying to parse the data (backend, Node.js using Cheerio):

```
var express = require('express');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
var app     = express();

app.get('/scrape/:username', function(req, res){
  var user = req.params.username;

  console.log('Processing request for ' + user);

  url = 'http://www.codecademy.com/' + user + '/achievements';

  request(url, function(error, response, body){
    if (!error){
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);

      var title, date
      var json = {
        achievements: [],
        meta: {
          request: {
            user: user,
            time: Date.now(),
          },
          server: {
            version: 1,
            contact: 'benedict@ovalbit.com'
          }
        }
      };

      console.log('Running parser and scraping achievements.');

      $('.achievement-card').each(function() {
        var data = $(this);
        title = data.children('h5').text();
        date = data.find('small.text--ellipsis').text();

        console.log('Title: ' + title);
        console.log('Date: ' + date);

        json.achievements.push({
          title: title,
          date: date
        });
      });

      res.type('application/json');
      res.json(json);
    }
  });
});

app.listen('3006');
console.log('Running on port 3006.');
```

For reference, [this](http://www.codecademy.com/users/BenedictLewis/achievements) is what a profile page looks like:

However, my each function never runs. Any thoughts?

Comment: @PatrickEvans There are `div`s with that class (among others) on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're generating the wrong URL as you're missing the `/users/` part before the user name. I just used that selector on your example achievements page and it works for me (node v0.10.30, cheerio v0.17.0, request v2.46.0):

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = 'http://www.codecademy.com/users/BenedictLewis/achievements';
request(url, function(err, res, body) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $('.achievement-card').each(function() {
    var data = $(this);
    title = data.children('h5').text();
    date = data.find('small.text--ellipsis').text();

    console.log('Title: ' + title);
    console.log('Date: ' + date + '\n');
  });
});
```

That outputs:

```
Title: Introduction to 'For' Loops in JS
Date: Feb  1, 2014

Title: 50 Exercises
Date: Feb  1, 2014

Title: Build "Rock, Paper, Scissors"
Date: Jan 18, 2014

Title: Introduction to Functions in JS
Date: Jan 18, 2014

Title: 25 points earned in one day
Date: Jan 11, 2014

Title: Choose Your Own Adventure!
Date: Jan 11, 2014

Title: 25 Exercises
Date: Jan 11, 2014

Title: Getting Started with Programming
Date: Jan 11, 2014

Title: 10 Exercises
Date: Jan 11, 2014

Title: First Lesson
Date: Jan 11, 2014

Title: Max Streak Count of 1
Date: Jan 11, 2014
```

Comment: @BenedictLewis You can't pass a url to `cheerio.load()`, it has to be the raw contents that you pass in (the html).

Comment: I just noticed you're using a different url. I think you're missing the `/users/` prefix before the user name.